# perl check if proxy is online

Tags: perl

How can I check if a proxy is online and properly working with perl? I was considering running a get operation and comparing output but i'll be running this check so frequently this overhead would be huge, any other more lightweight alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is exactly how you do it. If you use a light-weight method such as HEAD, TRACE or OPTIONS instead, you cannot know whether the proxy is actually useful or censoring or even subtly subverting the unencrypted data.

You can keep the overhead small by testing against a minimal useful HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Like daxim said, I think that testing against a very small HTML document is going to be lightweight enough for most scenarios.

The insuperable lightweight solution will be to use a web service that responds you with minimal data about your proxy IP address, if it is online and working fast enough, etc. This of course is going to include a third party(who's going to be doing the not so light work, doing the requests to all the proxies) and this, like everything, has their pros and cons.

I use this **[proxy checker](http://code.google.com/p/proxychecker/)** from Google code to do exactly what you need and I also obtain some more info of each IP address, like country and a couple of the proxy speed measurements. It's a very simple code that consumes a web service from http://proxyipchecker.com/ .

PS: The example is in PHP but is trivial to do the same in Perl.